# Bluetooth-Stick is not recognised

Tags: usb, drivers, motherboard, bluetooth

I got myself a new motherboard a few days ago. We are talking about the *Aorus XTREME X570*.
**The problem I have is the following:**

I use the microsoft surface keyboard which is connected via bluetooth.
The problem is that the bluetooth signal of the motherboard barely goes through my desk.

I have a bluetooth USB-Stick (ASUS USB-BT400) which I plugged into a different pc to verify that its working. But when I plug that stick into my new PC, it is not working the way it should.

My device manager gives me the following:

> The device could not be started. (Code 10)

I have tried downloading the bluetooth drivers for my motherboard but it didnt work.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would recommend to first disable the GIGABYTE bluetooth in device manager.
2. If then the driver from [ASUS](https://www.asus.com/Networking/USBBT400/HelpDesk_Download/) does not work, you should contact their support department.

Comment: Thanks! That was actually it :)